# what is the difference between 'action="#" and action="/" '

Tags: html, forms, action

what is the difference between
`action="#"` and `action="/"`

i have been asked to find the difference there but I can't

Comment: `action="#"` is the same as link to `href="#"`. It doesn't go anywhere but at the top of that page. The `action="/"` is the same as link to `href="/"`. The single slash `/` is root web URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. action="#" means it will redirect to the # after the main domain for e.g. [www.domain.com/#](http://www.domain.com/#) which show no change on page.
2. action="/" means it will redirect to  main domain for e.g. [www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/) which show the index page.